# MvvmCross : databinding programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I think I need to bind data programmatically to solve my problem.

I use a TabHost which hosts 2 Tabs.
I need to load the MvxBindableListView in the second tab when TabHost appears and keep the first tab as default tab.

What I'm doing is starting the second tab activity without problem because I check the process using this code:

```
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Page_ActivityView);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("activityView started");

        MvxBindableListView mvxBindableListView = FindViewById<MvxBindableListView>(Resource.Id.mvxBindableListView);
        mvxBindableListView.ChildViewAdded += new System.EventHandler<Android.Views.ViewGroup.ChildViewAddedEventArgs>(mvxBindableListView_ChildViewAdded);
    }
```

"activityView started" is displayed in output debugger, but MvxBindableListView.ChildViewAdded event isn't raised, only when I click the second tab.

So I suppose that MvxBindableListView is not databound.

Thanks in advance to help me loading my second tab programmatically.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem description. Can you explain more (show more code?) about how you are dynamically adding the Tabs? And about why you need to do this ChildViewAdded call programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ChildViewAdded` is an event that occurs when the ListView is rendered - at that time when it needs to 'draw list items', then it will ask its adapter for child Views for the screen. As you scroll down the list, it will then ask for more child views - but it will also reuse views - so for a simple list you should only ever (hopefully) get N+1 calls on ChildViewAdded for a list which shows N items at one time.

---

So it's perfectly possible for a list to be databound but never to call `ChildViewAdded` - that won't get called until the list is 'drawn'

---

Sadly the Xamarin docs aren't helpful here - http://docs.mono-android.net/monodoc.ashx?link=E%3AAndroid.Views.ViewGroup.ChildViewAdded

---

Note: if you do actually want to bind programatically, then you can do this to - using `Bind()` methods and extension methods. However, I haven't expanded on that here - as it doesn't sound like that's actually what you need!

Comment: I was using ChildViewAdded to get data from the listItem and get the UIControl but you tell me it is the wrong way to do like this:void mvxBindableListView_ChildViewAdded(object sender, Android.Views.ViewGroup.ChildViewAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            MvxBindableListView mvxBindableListView = (MvxBindableListView)sender;
            int indexOfChild = mvxBindableListView.IndexOfChild(e.Child);
            Customer customer= ViewModel.DataStore.GetCustomerFromIndex(indexOfChild);
     TextView textViewCustomer = e.Child.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewCustomer);

Comment: The problem is that I want to load the entire MvxBindableListView to get an UIControl inside each ListItem which seems impossible as only views displayed on the screen are available.

Comment: You can follow the discussion here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075521/monodroid-listview-load-the-entire-listview-in-background-and-get-an-uicontrol