# load the entire ListView in background and get an UIControl inside each ListItem

Tags: c#, listview, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I need to load a ListView entirely and get an UIControl inside each ListItem even if the item view is not displayed on the screen.

I tried the ChildViewAdded event, but it is raised only when the ListItem is displayed on the screen.

So, I need a way to prepare my UI ListView programmatically before displaying it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer - if you need a real View for each item in your list then you don't want to use a virtualized control like a ListView.

Instead you can use repeated custom views inside a vertical LinearLayout inside a ScrollView.

If using mvvmcross, you may find a MVXBindableLinearLayout helpful to do this - it has an ItemsSource and a Template just like the MvxBindableListView.

---

I've no idea whether what you are trying to do makes sense, but the above should help you do it if you want to!

Don't try using a linear layout for lists with lots of items - you'll run out of resources.

Comment: I changed my design to fit my needs. I found that ChildViewAdded event in MvxBindableListView is only raised for the first items visible on the screen, but when scrolling down the event is never raised again! Only when orientation changed and follow the previous behavior again. Don't know if it is a bug ?

Comment: Read my answer to your previous question. It's not a bug. It's how a list works - it reuses views.

Comment: A list can display MILLIONS of records - so it's designed so that you don't need one View per record - just enough Views to cover the visible screen.