# Multiple MvxBindableListView's in a single layout?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've been trying to place 3 MvxBindableListView widgets in my layout with no success.
Is there a way to do this so that each MvxBindableListView is fully displayed without inner scroll and for my "page" to be scrollable. 
This is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/MyCurrentProject.Client.UI"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="{}" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            local:MvxBind="{}" />
        <Mvx.MvxBindableListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            local:MvxBind="{}" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            local:MvxBind="{}" />
        <Mvx.MvxBindableListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            local:MvxBind="{}" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            local:MvxBind="{}" />
        <Mvx.MvxBindableListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            local:MvxBind="{}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Binds empty here, but fully working. The lists have a variable number of elements, so fixed height is not possible...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `MvxBindableLinearLayout` - but obviously consider that you could be using a lot of additional resources (memory, graphics objects, etc) if you display one or more long lists in their entirety.

Comment: Isn't there a way to set the height of the MvxBindableListViews to the full size of the list so that they don't scroll and I can use a ScollView?

Comment: I tried it and it sets the height of the List to the height of 1 list item... And with the List still scrollable... :(

Comment: you have to use MvxBindableLinearLayout for this with it's height set to wrap_content - see other questions which mention LinearLayout's like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914544/ssue-with-binding-to-gridlayout-to-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075521/load-the-entire-listview-in-background-and-get-an-uicontrol-inside-each-listitem

Comment: Thank you Stuart, the MvxBindableLinearLayout  did the trick indeed! I followed that link you posted in your previous commentary and it all works perfectly now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick to have your lists grow and then place them inside of a scrollview. See the code below. You would consume it the same way as a regular MvxBindableListView.

```
public class BindableExpandableHeightListView : MvxBindableListView
{
   public BindableExpandableHeightListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) { }

   public BindableExpandableHeightListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, MvxBindableListAdapter adapter) : base(context, attrs, adapter) { }

   private bool _isExpanded = true;

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        if (_isExpanded)
        {
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(int.MaxValue >> 2, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = LayoutParameters;
            layoutParams.Height = MeasuredHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexey, but I ended up using Stuart's method... ;)